An alternative formulation of continuum hypothesis.
I am searching to understand if the following sentence is equivalent to the continuum hypothesis: I think it is nice because it does not use cardinal arithmetic but only ordinal theory -hartog's number definition- and elementary set theory -power set and equipotence.

Statement 1
If $X$ is an infinite set then $\mathscr P(X)$ and $\mathfrak h(X)$ are equipotent, where $\mathfrak h(X)$ is the hartog's number of $X$.

So first of all let's we remember that if $A$ and $B$ are equipotent then even $\mathfrak h(A)$ adn $\mathfrak h(B)$ are: indeed if the inequality
$$
\mathfrak h(A)<\mathfrak h(B)
$$
held then there would be an injection from $\mathfrak h(A)$ to any subset of $B$ so that finally there would be an injection from $\mathfrak h(A)$ to a subset of $A$ and this is impossible.

$\mathbf{st. 1}\to\mathbf{CH}:
$Now the truth of st. 1 implies that $\mathscr P(\aleph_\alpha)$ and $\mathfrak h(\aleph_\alpha)$ are equipotent: however we know the equality
$$
\left|\mathscr P(\aleph_\alpha)\right|=2^{\aleph_\alpha}
$$
hold and by definition (right?) even the equality
$$
\aleph_{\alpha+1}=\mathfrak h(\aleph_\alpha)
$$
hold so that we conclude st. 1 implies continuum hypotesis.


$\mathbf{CH}\to\mathbf{st. 1}:$
Now let be $\alpha$ an ordinal such that
$$
|X|=\aleph_\alpha
$$
Well, if continuum hypothesis is true then the equality
$$
\left|\mathscr P(\aleph_\alpha)\right|=2^{\aleph_\alpha}=\aleph_{\alpha+1}=\mathfrak h(\aleph_\alpha)
$$
holds so that so that if $\mathfrak h(\aleph_\alpha)$ and $\mathfrak h(X)$ are equipotent (by above) and if even $\mathscr P(X)$ and $\mathscr P(\aleph_\alpha)$ trivially are then we conclude that st. 1 hold.

So I ask if actually st. 1 and continuum hypothesis are equivalent and so if I well proved this: could someone help me, please?

You mean the generalized continuum hypothesis (GCH) rather than CH.

Oh yeah, you're right!
